# Как установить linux на флешку?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Хочу установить Linux Mint на флешку. Именно установить, а не записать образ.

При записи iso-образа получается, что программы, устанавливаемые при загрузке с флешки, забываются при перезагрузке. Всякие настройки - тоже.

Хочу получить полноценную систему, но на флешке. Как этого добиться?

Comment: @IntFloat, я знаю. Сейчас с угробленным диском почти разобрался, потом буду ставить. На данный момент у меня ещё пара неясных моментов по ответу имеется, поэтому его не отметил. Но я собирался их сначала погуглить.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> полноценную систему

запустите установку и выберите «флэшку» в качестве целевого диска.

на неё же и загрузчик поставьте [на соответствующей стадии установки](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612988/178576).

Comment: LiveUSB успешно ставится и запускается на SD (не SSD - а "микро-флэшка"), прекрасно видится и читается, когда система запущена с другого Лайва, но для установки упорно не предлагает СДшку как устройство для установки, хотя СДшка пропатчена, как USB HDD. Есть ли способ провести установку при таких раскладах или установщик будет упорно отказываться от установки на USB устройства?

Comment: @SynCap, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, по ссылке — только инструкция по указанию устройства. и ни слова про разметку самого устройства (это совсем отдельная тема, которая в том вопросе, и, соответственно, в ответе, не затрагивается).

Comment: 1. Хм.. А где я вчера читал про 3 раздела? Мелкий в ext2 под grub, по размеру оперативки под подкачку и системный; по желанию ещё один для home. 2. А разве автоматическое разбиение на разделы в случае с флешкой не сработает? Или там его нет?

Comment: Кстати, а что ты считаешь по поводу [соседнего ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557767/178988), где рекомендуется отключать своп и отправлять temp на ram-диск, чтобы уменьшить запись на флешку? Неужели там настолько много операций записи, что флешка от этого сдохнет?

Comment: 1. не знаю. разделов может быть и один. «под grub» — точно не надо. раздел для swap-а по нынешним временам как-то под большим вопросом. его в конце концов можно и в файле держать. 2. подозреваю, что нет. ну, что там автоматизировать-то, при создании одного большого раздела на всё устройство? (ну, хорошо, двух, если раздел для swap-а таки нужен). 3. «много или мало?» — очень сложный вопрос. если в попугаях — то много. а если в удавах — всего ничего.

Comment: Насколько я помню, в случае жёстного диска у инсталлятора был флажок типа "снеси всё и разбей на разделы как сам считаешь нужным" - вроде я при установке на виртуалку использовал. Ожидал, что с флешкой он тоже так может :)

Comment: тут кардинальная ошибка в предположениях. дело не в типе блочного устройства, а в выбранном пункте: либо «сделайте мне всё зашибись», либо «я сам умный и знаю, что делаю» (это и есть «другой вариант» на скриншоте).

Comment: usb-creator-kde поможет, или нее?

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, с преступником фунтиком не знаком. да и зачем разбираться со всеми этими сонмами всяких «креаторов», если всё необходимое есть прямо под рукой, в программе установки?

Answer (score 2):

USB Live версия дистрибутива тоже может сохранять настройки при завершении. Так что не обязательно устанавливать. Например [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) может создать дополнительный раздел для сохранения настроим при записи образа диска (*"Space used to preserve files across reboots"*).

Если все же хотите установить, то действия ничем не отличаются от установки на жесткий диск (т.е. выбрать устройство, создать разметку, указать точки монтированная и выбрать раздел для установки)

Answer (score 2):

Установить `usb-creator-kde`. Создать загрузочную флешку. Получится live система с возможностью сохранять настройки, устанавливать программы, работать с данными.

[image: usb-creator-kde]

Для доступа к сохраненным данным (если вы не загрузились с флешки, а просто воткнули ее в работающую линукс-систему) нужно примонтировать файл на флешке, который называется `casper-rw`.

---

!!! Эта программа не будет записывать\устанавливать виндовс-системы !!!

Comment: Хм.. В соседнем ответе про unetbootin тоже про убунту. Подозреваю, они одну и ту же его возможность используют. В минте она тоже должна быть, как в его наследнике? Но со всеми остальными дистрибутивами не сработает... Верно?

Comment: почему не сработает? Хотя... Если Слэк так записывать\ставить то канешн не получится.(?) В минте думаю должна быть.

Comment: Потому что я прочитал первую строчку в окне на скриншоте?

Answer (score 2):

Программа YUMI (есть на виндовс и на линукс). Я скачивал портативную версию на Windows YUMI 2.0.4 (вот официальный сайт https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator).
Там в пару интуитивных кликов создается загрузочная флешка.

[image: Снимок окна программы]

1. Вставляем флешку, запускаем программу, выбираем ее, ставим галочку в форматировать в FAT32
2. Выбраем OS Linux, который будем закидывать на флешку, для того, чтобы программа правильно создала загрузчик
3. Указываем путь к файлу-образу дистрибутива
4. Создаем на флешке раздел, в который будут сохраняться все сделанные изменения. Например, если я загрузился с флешки, мне нужно настроить интерфейс, установить в систему русский язык (руссифицировать), запихнуть туда нужные мне программы (xNeur - Punto Switcher for Linux, CherryTree), дополнения для браузера. В этом разделе все изменения и будут храниться

Единственное, раздел не быстро создается, на флешке USB 2.0 10-15 минут подождать придется.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно вредно устанавливать на флешку линукс(для самой флешки вредно:)). Но я поступал очень просто, (может мой способ и не идеален, но работает). Ставим virtualbox:) (запускаем от рута, ато флешку не увидит). Подключаем в virtualbox виртуальный cd, подключаем в него образ. При включении виртуалки отдайте ей флешку(флешка из операционки отсоединится) и все вы можете ставить туда любую операционку(писал когда-то android, mint, ubuntu что угодно, ну кроме винды). Дальше, обязательно не делайте swap!!(это флеш накопитель, убьете его со своим swap буквально за месяца два)(перенести tmp в оперативку и еще пару папочек и вуля).

---

В этот раз не буду у вас отнимать этой любознательности, железо ваше творите.(учтите у флешек сектора ограничены циклами перезаписи, чем дешевле флешка тем меньше она проживет при активной записи, один битый сектор флешка мертва.)

Мы будем использовать Debootstap с помощью ее можно поставить любой дистрибутив(в пакетной зоне .deb) минимально с нуля. С помощью его я смог поставить Debian(рабочий на флеше, правда все разделы перенес в tmpfs), Ubuntu(так тестово). Отличие от обычной установки вы получаете самый минимум, можете выбирать архитектуру(хоть арм) ставить то что вам требуется. Правда без установщиков, все вручную. Единственное вам потребуется уже рабочий линукс на ином компе с доступом к сети(загрузит нужный минимум, продолжить установку на устройстве или на томже компе(если архитектура тажа)).

Описывать долго, вот вам ссылка https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Debootstrap .По поводу "Не устанавливайте его на нормальной системе Debian. " Возможно они имели ввиду что надо доставить такие важные пакеты как "sensors"(температура), "cpufreq-utils"(управление частотами проца), "иксы", "sddm"или"lightdm" но можно поставить оболочку и он сам поставит нужный вам ("sddm"или"lightdm")

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет программа [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), она сущесвует под любую операционную систему и она бесплатна. Она записывает установочный образ различных операционных систем. просто ищите live версию linux (например любую десктопную ubuntu) и тогда вы сможете не только ее устанавливать с флешки но и запускать её.

Ну и стоило бы поглугить и вы бы нашли [вот такое руководство](http://mintlinux.ru/blogs/ruskii-linux-mint-nastroika-obzory/sozdanie-live-usb-s-linux-mint-na-bortu.html).

Comment: 1. Речь шла об установке с сохранением того, что сделано во время работы системы. Не уверен, что описано такое. 2. По ссылке: _"где sdb1 - наша флешка (у вас может быть sdb4, sdb2 и так далее, поэтому будьте внимательны)."_ - разве? Как у флешки цифра может быть не 1? На ней больше 1 раздела? Вроде вряд ли. А вот sdc1, sdd1 и т. д. - запросто.

Comment: @Qweriy 1. я бы лучше вместо этого пользовался терминальным клиентом. 2. на флешке может быть больше одного раздела, к тому же контроллеры некоторых флешек умеют симулировать устройство физического привода (CD-DVD rom).

Comment: @Qwertiy насчет цифры, а если у вас две флешки воткнуты..

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно же уже настроенную под Вас систему записать на флешку. Со всеми нужными программами и оформлением - погуглите.